# yii2 override model method

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to create simple project on Yii2. Now I'm creating User functionality. I already created User model and CRUD with Gii. When I create new user or edit, model saves password in plain text. I want to override this functionality to have an ability to save password for example in md5 format.

In Zend Framework there was similar ability.
I have password field and when I want to change default setting password behavior I just created setPassword method in the model. 
Which way is correct for Yii2?

In my User.php model class I created setPassword($password) method but it is not executed (I check it putting var_dump inside).

Comment: Check how this is done in [Advanced Project Template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/models/User.php).

Comment: I want to understand how it works, I don't need it done, just understand

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Advanced Project Template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/models/User.php):

1. Model [SignupForm](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/models/SignupForm.php) is resposible for creating new User model.
2. Controller running this process is SiteController with action [Signup](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/controllers/SiteController.php#L149) - when SignupForm is properly `load()`-ed method `signup()` from SignupForm is called.
3. When data is [properly validated](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/models/SignupForm.php#L46) new instance of User class is initialised.
4. New password is set by calling `$user->setPassword($this->password);` - `$this->password` is raw plain text password chosen by user.
5. Method [setPassword()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/models/User.php#L161) sets `password_hash` property which is generated (hashed and salted) based on the plain-text password - this hashed password is stored in the database.
6. You can change the way password is hashed by modifying `setPassword()` (it's not recommended though).

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the `beforeSave` method [see here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeSave()-detail), and encrypt the password.

Alternatively, you could do this in the controller in the `actionCreate` method before calling `$model->save()`.